# Return to a section of a page after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page with various forms and what I would like to do is go to a certain part of the page after submission.

From everything I have read, I see that if I use a header() in php I will get a page reload - which I do not want to do as I don't want to lose a variable I am using - so I come across some scrollToAnchor js like -

```
function scrollToAnchor_name(anchorName) {
 location.hash = "#" + anchorName;
}
```

Which works fine with a link -

```
<a href="#bottom">bottom</a>
```

but I'm not sure how to trigger it via php - php because that is what i am using to process the form and set the variables.

I've seen one solution like

```
<?php
echo "function test";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">    run();      </script>';
?>
```

But because I know nothing about js, this means nothing to me, I did try -

```
echo "scrollToAnchor_name(anchorName);";
```

But that was a big miss.

Am I approaching this the right way and if so can someone give me some pointers on how I could trigger the above script from php?

Cheers

Comment: You can use form validator for form validation and for submitting use ajax so that it wont refresh your page and keep remaining on the form itself. Hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there's no condition for whether to scroll to specific element or not, you could just add the hash in the form directly

```
<form action="page.php#element">
   ...
```

I don't get why do you need to do this with PHP specifically, but still you could do

```
echo 'location.hash = "#element"';
```

Comment: His Javascript retrieve the anchor href content. So it wont retrive the data from action in form

Comment: Hi and thanks heaps, nicael. I didn't get the 

`echo 'location.hash = "#element"';`

I think that may have had something to do with the fact my php was at the top of the page and the script below it? Anyhow I did get the 

`<form action="page.php#element">`

to work. Thanks heaps again, really appreciated.